Find minimal sufficient statistic of this random sample with cursed support
Suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is a i.i.d random sample with probability mass function $p(x_i,\theta)$ where $x_i \in \{\theta,\theta+1,\theta+2,...\}$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. I claim that minimal sufficient statistic is $(X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)})$. Am I right?
Special case
If it is hard to find a minimal sufficient statistic for this problem, you can consider a special case where $p(x_i,\theta)=p(x_i)$ which means p does not depend on $\theta$.
General case
I also believe that my claim is true when $\theta \in A$ where $card(A) \ge 2$.
My Approach
If you try to use factorization theorem:
$$P(\textbf{X}=\textbf{x}) = {\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n} p(x_i,\theta) I_{ \{ \theta,\theta+1,...\} }(x_i) }$$where $I_{ \{ \theta,\theta+1,...\} }(x_i)$ is the indicator function. This is where we can't do anything because we can't factor the product of indicator functions, so I guess the minimal sufficient statistic is $(X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)}) $.
My Interpretation
I think ${\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n} I_{ \{ \theta,\theta+1,...\} }(x_i) }$ means "in order to find out $x_i$ is a valid observation, we need to know $\theta$ "
My Question
Is $(X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)})$ the minimal sufficient statistic?
I also asked this question in math stackexchange but I got no answer.

What is a minimal sufficient statistic is going to depend on the form of $p(x_i,\theta)$.  Since the sample is i.i.d., $(X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)})$ will be a sufficient statistic but may in some cases not be minimal.

@Henry Try to find a counterexample. Assume that $p(x_i,\theta)=(\dfrac{1}{2})^{x_i-\theta+1}$. Now find the minimal sufficient statistic.

Just out of curiosity, what is a "cursed support"?  Do you actually mean "curved support"?

In your example of $p(x_i,\theta)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x_i-\theta+1} I_{[\theta\le x_i]}$, the minimal sufficient statistic is $X_{(1)}$.  If instead $p(x_i, \theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}I_{[\theta\le x_i \lt 2\theta]}$ then the minimal sufficient statistic is $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$.  In both cases $(X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)})$ is sufficient but not minimal.

@Zhanxiong: in Modern Online English, 'cursed' means roughly 'very unusual, in an unpleasant and scary way, as if affected by a curse'. I think it came from Reddit

@Henry Well, $I_{ { \theta, \theta+1,... } }(x_i) \neq I_{ [\theta \leq x_i ] }$. Assume $\theta = \dfrac{1}{3} $ then $I_{ { \theta, \theta+1,... } }(\dfrac{1}{2} ) = 0$, but $I_{ [\theta \leq \dfrac{1}{2}] } = 1$.

@Zhanxiong Actually, I made that name since the problem comes from the support ${\theta,\theta+1,...}$. If you think it's inappropriate to use a made-up name in Stack Exchange,  I can change the title.

@ArshakParsa With that attitude and with $p(x_i,\theta)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x_i-\theta+1} I_{[x_i \in \theta, \theta+1, \ldots]}$ you might want to say a minimal sufficient statistic is $(X_{(1)}, {{X_{(i)}-X_{(1)}}})$ where ${{z_i}}$ means the set of fractional parts of $z_i$ and here will be ${0}$ with probability $1$ so can largely be ignored leaving just $X_{(1)}$:  checking all the observations are integer distances apart does not tell you about $\theta$.
